# Oracle Apex development

Tags: javascript, plsql, plugins, onclick, oracle-apex

In oracle apex I have used a plugin along with javascript files.I am doing a function calling from PLSQL code under sys.htp.p tag to the Javascript file and this returns a value Which is assigned in a variable inside this sys.htp.p tag. Need to use the value of the variable outside the sys.htp.p tag in the Whole PLSQL code.

I am facing problem to do so. Advise on the query

```
sys.htp.p('" id="Testing'||V_HOL_TYP||' " onclick="Test = myFunction('||V_HOL_TYP||'););
```

Answer (score 1):

The `htp.p` call is performed on the serverside, in the database. If you want to expose client side variables in the server you have do do that via page items, using the js namespace apex.item.

You can run javascript code on the page , either on page load (page attributes) or with a dynamic action on any kind of events.